# Javascript - Variable References Changing

Tags: javascript, variables

What types of variables change like so?

```
var int1;
var int2;
var int3;

int1 = 42;
int2 = int3 = int1;
int1 += 3;

int1      // 45
int2      // 42
int3      // 42



arr1 = {};
arr2 = arr3 = arr1;
arr1.ab = 5; 

arr1      // Object {ab: 5}
arr2      // Object {ab: 5}
arr3      // Object {ab: 5}
```

Like howcome int2 and int3 changed and arr2 and arr3 didn't? What types change like this?

Comment: Duplicate question of many.  I will go find one of the dups.

Comment: Primitives are immutable. Any computation with them produces a new value. Objects are mutable though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive data types (number, string and boolean) do not change if you change a reference of it, whereas composite data types *do* change.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7wkd9z69(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: This answer is a bit superficial. It doesn't explain what *reference* means in this context. If you are just saying that primitives are immutable and objects are not, that's correct.

Answer (score 3):

In javascript `Arrays & Objects` are passed by reference, so changing them one place affects others.

And primitives like `number`, `string` are passed by value, so changing them at one place doesn't affect on others.

## Primitives

```
var a,b;
a=10;
b=a;
```

So `b` & `a` has something like bellow structure

```
a ---1000----> [10] a is pointing to some location(lets 1000) which have value 10
b ---1004----> [10] b is pointing to some location(lets 1004) which have value 10
```

Lets we increment `a` by `1` now the value will be changed at the place `1000`.

```
a ---1000----> [11]
b ---1004----> [10]
```

## And in Arrays and Objects

```
obj1 = {}; // obj1 has a reference
```

`obj1` has an structure like bellow

```
------->1000--------->[{}]
obj1 -------1004----->[1000] //this '1000' is a reference which has a `{}` at it's place
```

This line

```
obj2 = obj1;
```

after this line `obj2` & `obj` share same reference
    ------->1000--------->[{}]
    obj1 -------1004----->[1000]
    obj2 -------1008----->[1000]

```
obj1.ab = 5;
```

this line is adding a field called `ab` to the reference of `obj1`

```
------->1000--------->[{ab:5}]
obj1 -------1004----->[1000]
obj2 -------1008----->[1000]
```

And because `obj1` & `obj2` have same reference, you are getting the field `ab` for both.

```
obj1      // Object {ab: 5}
obj2      // Object {ab: 5}
```

**Note:-** Any improvement in answer is appreciated.

Comment: That is not correct. Everything is passed by value. In case of objects, that value *is* a reference. Pass by reference is something else though. The biggest difference between objects and primitives is that objects are mutable.

Comment: @JhKaiz: This breaks if you mutate `obj1`. Simulating immutability through prototype inheritance only works one way and is more confusing than useful IMO. And again, everything is *pass by value* in JS. Wikipedia has a huge article explaining the different ways of passing values.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, I got the point. Removed my wrong solution. So,the only to pass by value of an Object that value != reference is make it be a function that return a new object, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the arrays share the *reference* between them while the integers share the *value*.
When a reference is changed, it affects others who have the same reference, but values are not like that since the js compiler allocates separate memory for them and modifying them affects only them..

To visualise reference types,

```
Reference --------> { ab : 5 } // Changing affects others with same reference
              ^
              | --> arr1
              | --> arr2
              | --> arr3
```

To visualise value types,

```
int1 ---> 42 --> +3 ---> 45 // Doesn't affect others
int2 ---> 42 
int3 ---> 42
```

Answer (score 0):

arr1 contain a reference for the empty list. Then arr3 receives a reference for the same list, and arr2 a reference for the same list. So when you make arr1.ab = 5, you added a item in that list named 'ab' and gave the value 5. But since arr2 and arr3 point to the same list, you will get the same value.